# How can I find whether each element in a list can be added based on the given values or not?

Tags: python, list, function, sum

So I have a function `findsum(s,g)` and I want to find whether elements in `s:list` can be the sum of any numbers in `g: list` or not... so for instance, if

```
s = [0,2,3,4,5]
g = [1,2,3],
```

the output should return

```
[False, True, True, True, True]
```

---

```
Explaination:
So 0 is false because nothing in g equals to or adds up to 0
2 is true because g contains a 2
3 is true because 2 and 1 in g adds up to 3
4 is true because if we add 2 to itself, 4 is the result
5 is also true because if we add 2 and 3 from g, we get 5
```

What I have tried:

```
def findsum(s,g): 
       for f in g:         
           for x in s:            
               if sum (x) == f:               
                  return True            
               else:                         
                  return False
```

What changes should I make to my code to make it work?

Comment: how many element in each list and what range of value can they take? because if g only contain values from 1 to 10 and f only contain about 20 values from 1 to 200 it is not the same as fi you can have any integer within f and j and 1000k different values in f?

Comment: Do you understand that for now your code doesn't do that at all ? as `x` is one int, so `sum(x) == x`, so you just check for equality, and if ONCE they are not equal you directly end the program

Comment: yep there are no restrictions for number of elements in the lists.. all that really matters is if the elements in g add up or equals to the elements in s, then the output is True for THAT element within the list

Comment: @azro oh really? what changes to my code do I have to make then in order for this to work??

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` to generates all combinations the given values (add a loop to generate all sizes)

```
list(combinations_with_replacement([1, 2, 3], r=3))
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 3), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3)]
```

Then check the sum, and you `return False` **only** at the final end, after testing all the combinations

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement    

def does_sum(values, target):
    for size in range(len(values)):
        for combi in combinations_with_replacement(values, r=size + 1):
            if sum(combi) == target:
                return True
    return False
    
def does_sum_multiple(values, targets):
    return [does_sum(values, target) for target in targets]
```

Note that if `1` is in the values, all results will be `True`

```
res = does_sum_multiple([1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(res)  # [False, True, True, True, True]

res = does_sum_multiple([2, 6], [0, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(res)  # [False, True, False, True, False]
```